# GUI cannot process the data fast enough and remains unusable for about 10 seconds

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Can someone please help me? I have a problem with my GUI. This receives too much data too quickly, so that the event handler blocks the GUI completely for user input.

A background program is to send a solution to the GUI (as text), but the GUI cannot process the data fast enough (72000 characters in 40 ms) and remains unusable for about 10 seconds.

This calls the background program:

```
SolveDelegate solve = Solve;
solve.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

And the receiver looks like this:

```
private delegate void AppendTextDelegate(string text);

private void AppendText(string text)
{
    if (GUITextBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke((AppendTextDelegate)AppendText, new object[] { text });
        // Thread.Sleep(5); // <= I don't like it at all.
     }
        else
            GUITextBox.appendText(text);
}

private void GUI_TextReached(object sender, TextReachedEventArgs e) => AppendText(e.Text);
```

Using Thread.Sleep(5) I can prevent the blockade on my PC. But in my opinion, this solution is not a good one. Is it possible to prioritize events or to run the TextBox in a separate thread, so that the GUI always remains operable? I've looked everywhere but haven't found any useful information yet.

Comment: Wpf? winforms? can't you just `Task.Run(() => {});` whatever it is that blocks  your stuff?

Comment: Why not store the data in a thread safe buffer, then marshal back to the ui at intervals in chunks, or use RX with throttling or buffering, or what ever cool things it calls it these days

Comment: This is just an attempt (Windows.Forms) for a larger program (then WPF). I need a reasonable solution that fills my interface with data by background processes while the user can simply continue.

Comment: What is the GUI doing with the text received?  You only need to process it on the main thread if it is being loaded into the user interface - such as into a combo-box.  Otherwise, process it on a background thread.  If it is being loaded into a control, please supply more detail - 1) what control?  2) What processing is taking place to get it into the control?  ie. What is `AppendTextDelegate` doing?

Comment: I had hoped events could be prioritized. But I'll have to put in a buffer. pity

Comment: If ```Thread.Sleep(5)``` is fixing the problem then it sounds like you have too many calls on your ```AppendText``` method. There are two big issues if that's the case.  One, string manipulation is something that needs to worked out carefully using optimal resources in recursive situations... Let me know if it's that and I'll assist and also recursive UI calls can be optimized various other techniques, one pointed out with proper thread management. Post all of the code involved and myself or another will surely give you a better solution. If I'm assuming wrong; post the code anyway pls.

Comment: You are trying to make what's called a `dashboard` many UI updates coming from live or streamed data.

Comment: Currently it is only a very simple WinForms program with a simple text box (only for testing). For this purpose I wrote the Puzzle Tower of Hanoi with a recursive and an iterative solution as a background process. The solution should then be sent to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are addressing the wrong problem - you are attempting to load too much data into your UI.  72000 chars is probable several thousand list entries, which does not provide a good experience for the user.

I suggest you try to filter the UI data you are loading down to < 100 items, either by providing filters (date etc) or, if capturing data, by using a value captured earlier to filter down to just a subset available in the next control.

If loading data into a grid, you may need to show more data but a good grid will often provide efficient ways to load data - what grid are you using?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to be a kind of dashboard for the Windows file system with real-time display. But I have no knowledge of how best to prepare the data so that tedious processes can be designed in such a way that the user can abort them or simply let them continue running in the background.